# К чему может привести использование static переменных?

Tags: c#, android, java, c, c++

Всем добрый вечер.
В процессе разработки приложения есть большая необходимость передачи каких либо переменных из одной Активити в другую. Я использовал всегда стандартный метод:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("key",from_to);
startActivity(intent);
```

И далее получение:

```
String from_to = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key", "null");
```

Но данный метод мне откровенно осточертел, и я решил делать это через **static** преременные так:

```
static String from_to;
```

Где то:

```
from_to = "Hello dear Android";
```

И в другой активити:

```
String from_to = First.from_to;
```

Но теперь меня мучает вопрос: ***чем же это может обернуться для меня?!***

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: а вообще будет весело, если в статических полях будете хранить ссылки на gui элементы или адаптеры.

Comment: Конечно весело! Но до такого моразма я еще не дошел)

Comment: Как все интересно. 

В результате немного почитал сейчас об Андроид. К сожалению, если написано кратко, то обычно неглубоко, а если полно, то читать некогда.

--

Чем-то все это напоминает сервлеты. Я так понял, что если у Вас речь о Java, то новая Activity с т.з. JVM будет потоком, которому доступен контекст потока, создавшего эту Activity. 

--

Из общих соображений использование static таким образом грозит лишь проблемами синхронизации, а вовсе не утечками памяти и NullPointerException 

(*если декларируемое полное восстановление предыдущего состояния при перезапуске - это правда*).

Comment: Передача параметров через глобальные переменные плоха тем, что такой подход не скалируется. Как только у вас появятся _два_ экземпляра класса, пытающееся воспользоваться одной и той же глобальной переменной, хаос гарантирован.

Если же код не рассчитан на дальнейшее развитие, пишите как угодно, хоть вообще без классов.

Comment: @VladD, научите, как на Java писать без классов?

Comment: @avp: Рассказываю. Создаёте один статический класс `Program`, все функции определяете как статические в этом классе, все «глобальные» переменные — как статические поля. Формально класс есть, но фактически это программирование без классов, т. к. нету семантического разделения на сущности.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Половина из написанного <del>откровенная чушь</del> не совсем верна. Если все делать по человечачьи то ужасов навроде `#сборщикмусораубил` или `#нарвалсянаnullpointer` можно избежать.

В Android есть такой класс Application, который является естественным синглтоном. Как пишется в умной книжке:

> When your Application implementation is registered in the manifest, it will be 
> instantiated when your application process is created. As a result your 
> Application implementation is by nature a singleton and should be implemented as 
> such to provide access to its methods and member variables.

Надо всего лишь создать свой собственный Application типа:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private static MyApplication singleton;
   private static MyVar myPreciousStaticVariable;

   // Returns the application instance 
   public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
   }

   public final void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate(); 
       singleton = this;
   }  
}
```

Правильно задекларировать в манифесте и вперед.

Нужные статические переменные (без фанатизма - то есть за минусом контекстов, юай элементов и проч. сумасшедшины) пихаем в `MyApplication` с правильной инициализацией в `Application.onCreate()` или в конструкторе (не забываем про lazy-init!), обкладываем статику геттерами (при необходимости и сеттерами) и все.

Далее в более менее любом месте проги делаем так:

```
myVar=MyApplication.getInstance().getMyPreciousStaticVariable();
```

**Update**
С освобождением ресурсов в `Application` это действительно проблема. Поскольку в `Application` нет явного колбэка вызываемого при закрытии. Немного утешает, что `Application` создается еще до момента создания любой из компонент приложения - `Activity`, `Service`, `Receiver` и проч. так что вы не сможете в `Application` явным образом создать эти объекты. А общее правило при создании объекта гласит - уничтожай там же где и создал. Так что создаем скажем в `Activity.onCreate()` - стало быть уничтожаем в `Activity.onDestroy()` и т.д. В общем хранение синглтон объектов в `Application` имеет свои ограничения - я согласен. В любом случае Application будет выгружен последним и все что останется после него будет убрано сборщиком мусора - не совсем кошерно, конечно.

Comment: А где освобождение?

Comment: Гм. О какой "правильной инициализации" идёт речь, если автор вопроса намеревается использовать static переменные для передачи параметром между `Activity`, то есть ни о каких `Activity.onCreate()` и `Activity.onDestroy()` и речи не идёт и, скорее всего, всё это добро будет инициализироваться в каком нибудь `OnClickListener`'е?

Comment: Ога, а еще и `TextView` будет передавать что ли... Пожалуйста без фанатизма :)

Answer (score 26):

обернется **NullPointerException** в тот прекрасный момент, когда приложение полностью выгрузится из памяти и будет открыто вновь (например, свернуто кнопкой "Домой" и открыто из списка последних запущенных).

допустим такая ситуация:
в **Activity_A** есть статичное поле, в **Activity_B** оно используется. текущий стек такой **Activity_A** -> **Activity_B.**  приложение выгрузилось из памяти, все ссылки на объекты, включая статичные поля, были обнулены. Приложение восстанавливается из памяти, первой будет загружена **Activity_B** (поскольку она на вершине стека), которая обращается к статичному полю в **Activity_A**, и тут же получает **NullPointerException**. Надеюсь понятно описал.

как раз-таки способ передачи через **Intent** более предпочтителен, поскольку все переданные параметры будут сохранены вместе с состоянием текущей активности и будут так же восстановлены.

Comment: @Роман Захаров ведь когда у меня включается новая активность, то перемнная в ней уже хранит значение статичной переменной из предыдущей активити, поэтому мне кажется, что это будет тоже самое. Интересно как работает механизм передачи данных через интенты.

Comment: @vanyamelikov, да такой способ передачи параметров будет работать и данные будут переданы. только потом не удивляйтесь наличию ошибок в консоли разработчика

Comment: @Роман Захаров я все равно до конца не понимаю, а где тогда хранятся переменные переданные при помощи интентов? Или они кэшируются каким то образом?

Comment: они передаются вместе с параметром Bundle в метод onSaveInstanceState(); если не ошибаюсь. либо будут включены в этот Byndle после выполнения этого метода

Comment: Написано неверно, поскольку при обращении к static класс опять загрузится и если статическая переменная инициализируется правильно (в статическом контексте или конструкторе) все пройдет гладко. Ужас-ужас возникнет, если статическая переменная инициализируется в неправильном месте, но это произойдет и без выгрузки активити из стека.

Answer (score 15):

Как минимум утечкой памяти. Поясняю.

Интернированные строки хранятся не в heapspace, а в permgen space. Сборка мусора в нем происходит по отдельным правилам, не так как в heap-e / young /tenured memory pools.

Сборщик мусора в Java не является универсальным механизмом, позволяющим программисту полностью забыть о правилах использования памяти и о том, в каких случаях осуществляется его работа.

Статичная переменная хранится своим классом, а как следствие, его загрузчиком (classloader). По причине внешнего использования увеличивается шанс, что сборщик мусора не соберёт данный экземпляр. Также зачастую в static-переменных кэшируется информация или же хранятся состояния, используемые несколькими потоками. Отдельным примером являются статичные коллекции. Хорошим же тоном при архитектурном проектировании служит полное избегание изменяемых статичных объектов — зачастую существует лучшая альтернатива.

Comment: Ответ веерный! Подробнее!

Comment: поподробнее можно? Я, конечно, не специалист в Java и Android-разработке, но что-то очень уж сомнительно выглядит ваше утверждение

Comment: Такие банальные вещи сборщик мусора Java, вероятнее всего, не пропустит и выгрузит из памяти все данные, ссылки на которые в приложении отсутствуют.

Comment: Всё верно, GC не будет трогать статичные переменные как минимум до тех пор, пока не будет выгружен соответствующий class loader.

Comment: @0xFFh,@vanyamelikov обновил ответ.

Comment: Написано неверно, поскольку при обращении к static класс опять загрузится и если статическая переменная инициализируется правильно (в статическом контексте или конструкторе) все пройдет гладко. Ужас-ужас возникнет, если статическая переменная инициализируется в неправильном месте, но это произойдет и без сборщика мусора.

Comment: @Barmaley: ТС хочет использовать статические переменные для передачи параметров, так что в рамках вопроса статическая переменная **с гарантией** будет инициализирована «неправильно».

Answer (score 4):

Тема старая, но всегда актуальная. Все ответы хороши, но забыт один довольно редкий случай, когда части приложения запущены в разных процессах.

Теория здесь: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Так вот в случае межпроцессной коммуникации никакие статические переменные не помогут. В новом процессе загрузится класс по новому и все статические поля будут пустыми. И только `Intent` + `Bundle` + `Parcelable` вам смогут доставить данные в новый/иной процесс.