# Где лучше создавать Retrofit клиент?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Я обычно создавала Retrofit клиент в классе App в onCreate(), но услышала мнение, что это неправильно, так как по сути получается, что это не Синглтон. Где и как лучше создавать Retrofit клиент?

Мой пример кода:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static MessengerApi service;
    private static OkHttpClient client;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor = new HeaderInterceptor();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(MessengerApi.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему он не синглетон? Он является синглетоном. Он создается один раз при старте приложения. OnCreate у App вызывается один раз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаю ретрофит в BaseApiManager

```
  public BaseApiManager(final String baseUrl) {
    final Context ctx = IsoverApplication.getInstance();

    mMainHandler = new WeakHandler(ctx.getMainLooper());
    final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor("isover", "isover2016"))
                                                                   .cookieJar(new MemoryCookieJar())
                                                                   .addInterceptor(new EmptyBodyToJsonInterceptor())
                                                                   .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
    builder.cache(new Cache(ctx.getCacheDir(), SIZE_OF_CACHE))
           .interceptors()
           .addAll(getAdditionalInterceptors());
    mClient = builder.build();
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
                                      .client(mClient)
                                      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                                      .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory())
                                      .addConverterFactory(createConverterFactory())
                                      .callbackExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
                                      .build();
  }
```

,

который является синглтоном

```
  public static BaseApiManager getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new BaseApiManager();
    }
    return sInstance;
  }
```

getInstance() дергаю на каждый запрос, т.е. потецниально ретрофит может создаваться каждый раз, на каждый запрос

Answer (score 1):

Вы все правильно делаете, в `Application` ему самое место, но я бы не советовал хранить состояние в static переменных, есть разные [мнения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262169) по этому поводу. Также я бы посоветовал использовать dagger для этих целей.