# Глобальные переменные в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Собственно вопрос про глобальные переменные в Kotlin(если они вообще есть)
Предположим я хочу создать переменную Address типа String и где то в теле класса в функции присвоить ей некоторое значение

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)  {
    if (requestCode === PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode === AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            val Adress =("" + place.getName() + ","+ place.address)
        }
    }
}
```

Я записываю в нее данные и по идеи будь она глобальной в случае если после я обработаю действие

```
    fun sendMessage(view:View) {
    if(Adress.isNotBlank()){
        println(Adress)
        println("IsNotBalnk")
    }else{
        println(Adress)
        println("IsBlank")
    }
    println("This fragment worck")
}
```

я получу ответ в логе. 
`адрес;IsNotBalnk;This fragment worck` 
Но на практике я не знаю получится ли реализовать(и как реализовать) такую стандартную для си подобных языков вещь и как итог в логе получаю

```
IsBlank;This fragment worck
```

Answer (score 3):

Глобальные переменные в Котлине есть, использовать их просто, но если речь идет о Андроиде, то не рекомендуется. Почему?

Потому что они компилятся в статические переменные синтезированного компилятором класса. Подробнее здесь:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

А о статических переменных в ракурсе Андроида уже много копий сломано, как пример:
[К чему может привести использование static переменных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262169/%D0%9A-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-static-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Так что пишите код in Android way, и наступите на меньшее количество граблей.